# Angularjs and Requirejs: Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-routing, angular-amd

I started using angularjs to create a single page application and wanted to add dynamic templates (views and controllers). I read on the web that I should use requirejs for doing this so I did.
I followed this tutorial @ https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD and tried to follow the steps.

When I wanted to open the page I get those two errors on my console:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/modulerr?p0=WebApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.25%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DWebApp%0AD%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A450%0AZc%2Fb.module%3C%2F%3C%2Fb%5Be%5D%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A1%0AZc%2Fb.module%3C%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A1%0Ae%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A267%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A207%0Agc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A309%0Afc%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A170%0Afc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A387%0AXc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A415%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A214%3A469%0Aa%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A145%3A67%0A

and this one

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/modulerr?p0=WebApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.25%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dwebapp%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.25%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dwebapp%250AD%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fpollit%252Fapp%252Flibs%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A450%250AZc%252Fb.module%253C%252F%253C%252Fb%255Be%255D%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fpollit%252Fapp%252Flibs%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A1%250AZc%252Fb.module%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fpollit%252Fapp%252Flibs%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A1%250Ae%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fpollit%252Fapp%252Flibs%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A267%250Ar%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fpollit%252Fapp%252Flibs%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A288%250Ae%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fpollit%252Fapp%252Flibs%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A207%250Ae%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fpollit%252Fapp%252Flibs%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A284%250Ar%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fpollit%252Fapp%252Flibs%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A288%250Ae%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fpollit%252Fapp%252Flibs%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A207%250Agc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fpollit%252Fapp%252Flibs%252Fangular.min.js%253A36%253A309%250Afc%252Fc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fpollit%252Fapp%252Flibs%252Fangular.min.js%253A18%253A170%250Afc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fpollit%252Fapp%252Flibs%252Fangular.min.js%253A18%253A387%250Ac.prototype.bootstrap%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fpollit%252Fapp%252Flibs%252FangularAMD.min.js%253A7%253A3485%250Aa%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fpollit%252Fapp%252Flibs%252Fangular.min.js%253A145%253A67%250A%0AD%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A450%0Ae%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A97%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A207%0Ae%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A284%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A207%0Agc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A309%0Afc%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A170%0Afc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A387%0Ac.prototype.bootstrap%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2FangularAMD.min.js%3A7%3A3485%0Aa%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpollit%2Fapp%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A145%3A67%0A

I think they are both similar errors. I guess the error is coming from **app.js** file and this is my code:

```
define(['angularAMD'], function (angularAMD) {
var app = angular.module("WebApp", ['webapp']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/",
        angularAMD.route({
            templateUrl: 'app/src/home/index.html',
            controller: 'index',
            controllerUrl: 'app/src/home/'
        })
    );
});

return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
});
```

and **main.js**

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "app",

paths: {
    'jquery' : 'libs/jquery.min',
    'general' : 'libs/general',
    'angular' : 'libs/angular.min',
    'angularAMD' : 'libs/angularAMD.min',
    'ngload' : 'libs/ngload.min'
},

shim: {
    'angularAMD' : ['angular'],
    'ngload' : ['angularAMD']
},

deps: ['app']
});
```

and now my template files
**index.js:**

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
app.factory('MainController', function (...) {

});
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="appheader">
<div class="container" style="text-align:right">
    <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a>
    <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></a>
</div>
```

So as you can see I have those two files in **app/src/home/index.(html/js)**
And other files are located at **app/** while **./** is the path of **index.html (main page)**

I really hope for help for my project and thanks in advance. :)

***EDIT*** ***EDIT*** ***EDIT*** ***EDIT***

Here we go:
**./index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="WebApp">
<head>
    <title>Index Index Index :)</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=100%, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/yadbocss.css" />
    <script data-main="app/main" src="app/libs/require.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="main">
                <div ng-view>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**./app/main.js**

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "app/",

paths: {
    'jquery' : 'libs/jquery.min',
    'general' : 'libs/general',
    'angular' : 'libs/angular',
    'angularAMD' : 'libs/angularAMD',
    'ngload' : 'libs/ngload',
    'ngRoute' : 'libs/ngRoute'
},

shim: {
    'angularAMD' : ['angular', 'ngRoute'],
    'ngRoute' : ['angular'],
    'ngload' : ['angularAMD']
},

deps: ['app']
});
```

**./app/app.js**

```
define(['angularAMD'], function (angularAMD) {
var app = angular.module("WebApp", []);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/",
        angularAMD.route({
            templateUrl: 'src/home/index.html',
            controller: 'index',
            controllerUrl: 'src/home/index'
        })
    );
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
});
```

**Error report**

**1**

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module WebApp due     to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'WebApp' is not available! You either     misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module     ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
...
```

**2**

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module WebApp due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider
minErr/<@http://localhost/pollit/app/libs/angular.js:68:12
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using routeprovider without adding it.

Angular is made up of lost of modules so you should include it in the module like

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

and link it in your html

```
<script src="angular-route.js">
```

Google CDN
e.g. //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-route.js

also change your version of angular so you dont use min. min.js is used for production and gives you crappy errors like the one you have there.

Comment: Hello, now I added angular-route via main.js and replaced the .min files. But now it says `Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module WebApp due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'WebApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument...`

Comment: in your index do you have `<html ng-app="WebApp">`?

Comment: Yes I have this. And somewhere below I have `<div ng-view>
     </div>`

Comment: I think it doesn't load ngRoute.js... I don't know why. If I include it inline to the index html file then I get **TypeError: angular is undefined** in ngRoute.js... I'm very confused.

Comment: show your index.html and we'll see if there's anything obvious in that

Comment: I've edited my post. There is now a edit section below the original.

Comment: i dont see where u call your angular module webApp on the index or in your require.js there should be a script tag linking it or linking main.js if main.js has links to all of your other js files

Comment: wait i see data-main. so you need to add a ref to the module you created. in main.js there should be a ref to WebApp

Comment: What does this mean, what is ref in angular/required? I'm very new to this, can you help me here our please?

Comment: ok so by ref i mean look at paths and shim, you see all the different angularjs modules in there (ngload, ngRoute) well the module you created (WebApp) is no different and should also be referenced in here.

Comment: I added to paths `'WebApp' : 'WebApp'` and shim `'WebApp' : ['jquery', 'angular', 'angularAMD', 'ngload', 'ngRoute'],`but still same error...

Comment: dono what to suggest, I know angular but im not familiar with require, i normally add my modules with a script tag like `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/module.js"></script>`

Comment: Ok... requirejs is adding the files too but I think I don't know how to manage them. But anyway thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Hello again... now the site is loading the view but not the controller and I get this error: `Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/ng/areq?p0=index&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined` Any idea?

Comment: you got this error with the none minified version of angular?

Comment: yes... it's the first line. The message is much longer

Comment: I fixed the problem... Thanks for your help. I found help @ http://www.javascripthtml.com/load-dynamically-javascript-file-in-angularjs-with-requirejs/